# Java - Zonedatetime - Without Daylight Saving

Tags: java, dst, datetime-conversion, zoneddatetime

I have a DTO which returns year, month, day and hour. So passing the value from the DTO to ZonedDateTime.of method. Here, the time is being passed as 10AM PST. So, trying to convert that to UTC.

When passing month as 5, it returns the start time 17PM and when passing month as 2 it is returning the start time as 18PM UTC. It is considering day light saving. It is supposed to be 18PM UTC always irrespective of the month. Is there any way to ignore day light saving here?

```
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

  final ZonedDateTime jobStartDateTimeZ = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 1, 10,
                    0, 0, 0, tz.toZoneId());

  Instant startTime = jobStartDateTimeZ.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();

  System.out.println("Start Time "+startTime);
```

We use a legacy system and the string will be in "America/Los_Angeles" in DB and there can be any time zone like "America/Bahia". We want to handle with this format for any timezone.

Comment: If you want it not to observe daylight savings, don't use a time zone which observes daylight savings. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8")` gives a fixed offset (even though it looks like the `+` is wrong).

Comment: @AndyTurner Can you elaborate and turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a hack; but it works.

```
    ZoneId tz = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    final ZonedDateTime jobStartDateTimeZ = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, tz);
    Instant startTime = jobStartDateTimeZ.toInstant();
    // add summer time (DST)
    startTime = startTime.plus(tz.getRules().getDaylightSavings(startTime));
    System.out.println("Start Time " + startTime);
```

This prints

> Start Time 2017-02-01T18:00:00Z

This doesn’t depend on the time zone being America/Los_Angeles or Pacific/Pitcairn, it doesn’t depend on the time zone using summer time (DST) or not. It just compensates for the summer time if one is in effect at the instant in question. If no summer time, 0 is added.

As an aside, don’t use the outdated `TimeZone` class. The modern `ZoneId` is a fine replacement. Also `withZoneSameInstant()` is unnecessary when you convert to `Instant` afterwards anyway,

Comment: It works great and i feel this is the right way to do if the timezone string is "America/Los_Angeles" or so. Hope, this will work for countries where daylight saving is not observed.